# How to scrape HTML table data using PHP

Tags: php, html

Edit: didn't make this clear. I'm using PHP

I'm trying to make a modernised Boxrec website, I'm scraping data from Wikipedia. In each Wikipedia page for a boxer, they have a table of their fights. I've successfully extracted the wins, losses & draws data from a different table. How would I use PHP to extract the fight table data into some kind of (2D?) array of pure text?

Here is a link to the table (It's the second table, the bigger one)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_Ray_Robinson#Professional_boxing_record

Here is the code I tried (I may be completely off with this)

```
$dom = new domDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($table);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        echo $cols[2];
}
```

And that gives me

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity,
> line: 4375 in C:\xampp\htdocs\boxing\search\index.php on line 38

Comment: Edited original post

Comment: looks like your HTML is not valid : `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag ...`

Comment: Just to follow up: did you have the chance to try the posted code?

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems I see:

1. `$tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');` will always give you the second table in the page which would be the table in the Personal stats block on the right
2. As `$cols[2]` is not an object of simple type, you will receive a warning rather then the content. Use `echo $cols[2]->textContent` to output the inner text.

I would recommend to load all tables and then check based on a table heading that is distinct in the results table if you are parsing the results table. Then extract the appropriate columns.

**Sample code:**

The below code only shows how to check for the sample heading "Result" in the table and will then output the results column. Please adapt it to your desired purpose.

```
<?php
$table = file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_Ray_Robinson');

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($table);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

foreach ($tables as $singleTable) {
    try {
        $rows = $singleTable->getElementsByTagName('tr');
        // check if we are parsing the right table:
        $row1= $rows[0]->getElementsByTagName('th');
        
        $isResultTable= FALSE;
        foreach ($row1 as $th) {
            if (trim($th->textContent) === 'Result') {
                $isResultTable = TRUE;
            }
        }
        
        if (!$isResultTable) continue;
        
        foreach ($rows as $row) {   
            $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
            echo $cols[2]->textContent;
        }       
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        print_r($ex);
    }
}
```